# Reduce Form spacing between sections SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

I'm trying to make a notes app with SwiftUI and I'd like to show the notes similar to the [Apollo Reddit app](https://apolloapp.io) does.

The way it shows the post isn't anything special, it just shows the posts using an interface similar to a list with `GroupedListStyle()`, but with less spacing between sections.

I've tried a lot of tricks to reduce this spacing, but none of them seems to work.

#### TL;DR

**I've got this**:[image]

**And I want this**:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Here's my code**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NotesView: View {

    let array = [
        Note(title: "Mi pana miguel letra", content:
        """
        [Intro: Keyan JRN & Producer Tag]
        El pana Miguel, yah, ey
        El pana Miguel, yah, ey (Snorkatje)
        Mi pana, mi pana, yeah
        Mi pana, mi pana, yeah
        Mi pana, mi pana, yeah, eh-eh
        Uh-uh-uh-uh-uh-uh

        [Estribillo]
        Ha-ha-hace un rato conocí al pana Miguel
        No-no voy a mentir, se ve bastante fresco
        (Ey, tío, ¿conoces a IlloJuan?) ¿Quién?
        (IlloJuan) No, que quién te ha preguntado (No-oh)
        Ha-hace un rato conocí al pana Miguel (Pana Miguel)
        No voy a mentir, se ve bastante fresco (Bastante fresco)
        Y el desgraciado de Matías que se vaya ya (Uh-uh, uh, uh)
        Prefiero quedarme aquí con mi pana, sentado
        """
        ),
        Note(title: "Note 02", content: "This is a test note."),
        Note(title: "Note 03", content: "This is a test note that is supposed to be longer than just 3 lines to test the note preview. Since I cba to write...")
    ]

    @ObservedObject var searchBar: SearchBar = SearchBar()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            List {

                if array.count > 0 {
                    ForEach(
                        array.filter
                        {
                            searchBar.text.isEmpty ||
                                $0.id.localizedStandardContains(searchBar.text)
                        },
                        id: \.self
                    ) { eachNote in

                        Section {
                            NoteView(note: eachNote)
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                    }
                } else {

                    NavigationLink(destination: NotesTextEditor()) {
                        Text("Create a new post")
                    }

                }


            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

            .add(self.searchBar)

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is to use custom a-la group separator, instead of standard.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 on some replicated code.

[image: demo]

```
List {
    ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(self.array[i].title)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text(self.array[i].content)
                .padding(.horizontal)

            if i != self.array.count - 1 { // don't show for last
                Rectangle().fill(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                   .frame(height: 16) // << fit as you need
            }
        }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // << avoid extra space
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```