# Reducing space between sections for grouped List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I've been trying to reduce the space between sections in a list with the `GroupedListStyle()` applied without any luck.

[image: Grouped list image]

Code from above screenshot:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            Section {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            Section {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")

            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is default layout. But possible solution was provided in [Reduce Form spacing between sections SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186463/12299030).

Comment: I have same problem. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 7):

You can add it outside the view like this

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        init() {
           UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
        }

        var body: some View {}
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS15+ since UICollectionView is used under the hood now

Answer (score 7):

iOS 13-15 List is UITableView (add code below in init):

```
UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

iOS 16-17 List is UICollectionView (add code below in init):

```
var layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
layoutConfig.headerMode = .supplementary
layoutConfig.headerTopPadding = 0
layoutConfig.footerMode = .supplementary
let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
UICollectionView.appearance().collectionViewLayout = listLayout
```

iOS 17:
The previous solution still works, but there is a new method:

```
.listSectionSpacing(0)
```

Changes you apply to UITableView.appearance() and UICollectionView.appearance() will also have an effect on all others Lists in your app. But you can apply changes only for current List using **swiftui-introspect** with code above replacing UITableView.appearance() and UICollectionView.appearance() by tableView and collectionView

```
.introspectTableView { tableView in
    // code below
}

.introspectCollectionView { collectionView in
    // code below
}
```

Comment: None of this works for me. listSectionSpacing adds space between section title and section content, not between the sections. And headerMode supplementary actually crashes the app

Answer (score 5):

In `iOS 17+` List has a modifier called `listSectionSpacing` which you can use to specify the gap

```
.listSectionSpacing(8)
```

Comment: That's iOS 17+. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this solution but I thought back to how `UITableView` works and guessed that it was probably the footer spacing causing this.

I added:

```swift
UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

to the init of the view and that seems to have worked.

I am aware that this sets that appearance globally so potentially it will be good to reset that value when the view disappears.

Comment: How do you add this to the View?

Comment: You can put this in the init of the view. Although I have since found it much better to use the LazyVStack instead of a List. It isn't backed by UITableView so you don't have all of these problems.

Answer (score -4):

You can use .listRowInsets() for your section and use a negative value for the bottom.

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0,leading: 0,bottom: -20,trailing: 0))
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: In my case it works.

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't. What's your min iOS sdk?

Comment: this changes row padding. Not section spacing. Only appears to work works in plain lists because they have a white background.